# How to properly remove all labels from form

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
        foreach (Control controlo in this.panel1.Controls)
        {

            if (controlo is Label)
                panel1.Controls.Remove(controlo);
        }
```

But it is only removing "one yes, one no".. Can someone fix my code?

Comment: are your labels inside the same panel?

Comment: are the other lables in panel1?

Comment: You are changing the collection your are iterating.  You must go backwards or make a copy of the collection that cannot be affected with this.panel1.Controls.OfType<Control>.ToArray().